# An internal error occurred during: "Validating GWT components". GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, garbage-collection

Eclipse crashing when I am trying to debug GWT module in hosted/dev mode.

[image]

I think things are going out of memory. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by increasing the memory of Eclipse itself. Added following in `eclipse.ini` file.

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: you can also use [JRebel Free Eclipse Optimization Tool](http://zeroturnaround.com/free/optimizer-for-eclipse/?utm_source=mkto&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=EO_GA)

Comment: @Cataclysm Is this a plugin to optimize eclipse memory?